# PHP - Change value with function reference not work in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion, reference

I want to change the values in multidimensional array using a function:

I have this:

```
$arr1 = array( 1 , array( 2, 3 ) );

// NOTE the & in function

function change_value_in_array( &$array ){
  foreach( $array as $k=>$v ){
    if( is_array( $v ) ){
      change_value_in_array($v);
    }else{
      $array[$k] = $v*10;
    }
  }
}

change_value_in_array($arr1);

var_dump($arr1);
```

OUTPUT:

```
$arr1 = array( 10 , array( 2, 3 ) );
```

I WANT THIS OUTPUT:

```
$arr1 = array( 10 , array( 20, 30 ) );
```

Comment: `$v` isn't no more a reference to the original array but a copy of an item, replace it with `$array[$k]` or use `foreach ( $array as $k=>&$v)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found the solution, I dont known if is the best way, but... (editing post with solution). :)

Comment: Your actual "solution" makes few sense since the original goal (if I understand well) is to write a "procedure" (that changes the parameter value) more than a "function" (that returns a value). The two ways are possible, but the advantage of the first way is to avoid the array copy.

Comment: I edited the post with your solution, is the simplest way... Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Now you can try to write it without using `$array[$k]` and using a reference in the foreach loop.

Comment: You are correct, the two methods works, with & in foreach and with $array[$k]... I dont know the best in terms of performance, but the beautiful way maybe is the & in the foreach.... I will update the post. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

COMPLETE SOLUTION: = Casimir answer is best solution...

```
$arr1 = array( 1 , array( 2, 3 ) );

// NOTE the & in function
// If use the & in foreach loop, the $v will be the reference and not a copy. Maybe the simplest way.

function change_value_in_array( &$array ){
  foreach( $array as $k=>&$v ){
    if( is_array( $v ) ){
      change_value_in_array($v);
    }else{
      $v = $v*10;
    }
  }
}

change_value_in_array($arr1);

var_dump($arr1);
```

NOTICE: This answer was lifted from Question text as written by OP.